# Need some help on tomcat URL mod_rewrite or mod_jk

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, tomcat

I am trying to remove the context name from the URL of my server.

Current URL - `http://www.domainname.com/MyApp/`

What I need to make is to make it available at - `www.domainname.com/`

So it is only going to host one main app and that needs to be displayed when we open `www.domainname.com/` on browser.

I have already tried couple of things like below -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(Context/.*)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /Context/$1 [P,L]
```

OR

```
redirect permanent /MyApp/ abcd://domainname.com
```

OR

Using JKMount -

```
JkMount /MyApp/* ajp13
JkMount /MyApp* ajp13
```

OR

Deploy war file to ROOT of tomcat and make relevant chagnes in web and server.xml 
All of these aren't working and I keep getting a intenal error.
I need a way to basically trim the tomcat URL to make short.

Comment: Is there a link with "www.domainname.com/"? I mean do you plan to do other rewrite rules for other domains that will use your app too?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `http://www.domainname.com/MyApp/` works as is... shouldn't you be able to just use your final RewriteRule? Just drop the RewriteCond and the 'P' flag.

Or if you're going to use mod_rewrite to do the proxy with the 'P' flag, don't you need to use the full URL in the RewriteRule? Something like `http://tomcatserver:tomcatport/Context/$1`

Comment: @matthew
Thanks Matthew though I did try with following as per your suggestion though it doesn't seem to have worked out - 
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /Foldername/$1 [P]
Instead of (.*), I used following - 
RewriteRule ^/(/.*)$ /GroupAGWeb/$1 [P] OR RewriteRule ^/(http://abc-xyz.paint-domain.com/.*)$ /Foldername/$1 [P]

Comment: I don't think you want the P flag. If you've set up the Proxy with Mod_jk I don't think you also need to tell mod_rewrite to do the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You should stop using mod_jk and start using mod_proxy.  I run tomcat on port 8080.  The web app that powers my site has an internal url like `http://localhost:8080/mysite`  I use mod proxy to make it available at `http://mysite.example.com/`  I use a firewall to ensure that only port 80 is accessible from the outside world.  mod_proxy is much more flexible than mod_jk.  Tomcat makes application available both http port 8080 and through the ports that mod_jk uses by default, so you likely won't even have to change your tomcat settings.

My apache configuration looks like this for that site

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    Servername mysite.example.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/mysite/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /mysite /
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain localhost mysite.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The cookie stuff is so that session cookies get translated by mod_proxy correctly.   You can also have mod_proxy rewrite the links if you need to.  In my case, my web app handles that.